# Is CreateDatabaseIfNotExists.InitializeDatabase atomic?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This seems like an obvious question, but is `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists.InitializeDatabase` atomic?

Currently I have code similar to below.  This an attempt to make sure that either database creation completes fully, or the database doesn't exist.

```
public class MyContext : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>
{
    public override void InitializeDatabase(MyContext context)
    {
        base.InitializeDatabase(context);

        //Removed custom initialization code
    }

    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        //Removed adding / updating seed data

        context.SaveChanges();

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}

public static class DbCreator
{
    public static void CreateDatabase()
    {
        using (MyContext dbContext = new MyContext())
        {
            try
            {
                var dbIntializer = new MyDbInitializer();
                dbIntializer.InitializeDatabase(dbContext);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                dbContext.Database.Delete();

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked in some obvious places for an answer such as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696403(v=vs.113).aspx.

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3

Comment: Does it matter? Do you really expect two calls at the exact same moment when the database has not yet been created?

Comment: Just check context.Database.Exists() when you need to know. https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/prevent-ef-migrations-from-creating-or-changing-the-database/

Comment: DML is most of the time not transactional. Create database is not transactional. By loosing the transactional part, this is not an atomic action anymore so no is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Thank you, that answered my question.